# Adding alternatively a class in <li> element of a same list in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list to which I would like to add 2 css class alternatively - (`classOne` and 
`classTwo`) in jQuery.

```
<ul>
<li>el 1 </li>
<li>el 2 </li>
<li>el 3 </li>
<li>el 4 </li>
<li>el n </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to get this

```
<ul>
<li class="classOne">el 1 </li>
<li class="classtwo">el 2 </li>
<li class="classOne">el 3 </li>
<li class="classTwo">el 4 </li>
<li class="classOne">el n </li>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is the jsFiddle of the fastest option: http://jsfiddle.net/KSrS2/1/ and this is the jsPerf comparing other options: http://jsperf.com/looping-through-li-testing-if-even-odd/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('li:odd').addClass('classOne');
    $('li:even').addClass('classtwo');
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DrZYQ/

Updated for better performance,

Or you can try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $('li').filter(':odd').addClass('classOne');
    $('li').filter(':even').addClass('classtwo');
});
```

Source from http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Note that `:odd` and `:even` are relatively slow, because `querySelectorAll` doesn't support them. This means that jQuery has to do the filtering itself. If you use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` jQuery will only do the work if the browser can't do it natively. It will therefore be much faster. Since the elements are all children of the same parent, the selectors are equivalent.

Comment: My solution is way more performant: http://jsperf.com/looping-through-li-testing-if-even-odd/4

Answer (score 2):

If this is for styling reasons, you don't need to use jQuery, as long as you're targeting relatively modern browsers:

```
li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    /* some styles */
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
    /* some other styles */
}
```

If you genuinely need the classes, it's relatively easy to do with jQuery. You could do it with selectors like above, but that will probably be slower. The quickest way is probably this:

```
$('li').addClass(function(idx) {
    return (idx % 2 === 0) ? 'classOne' : 'classTwo';
});
```

Comment: Nitpick: I think the class names have to be swapped or remove `=== 0`.